# plotting bar chart make negative bars different colour to positive bars

Tags: matlab

I am plotting a bar chart in Matlab. I would like to know if it is possible to base the colours of the bars based on a simple condition? I would like all the positive bars to be say blue and the negative ones to be red. If this is possible can you please tell me how I can going about doing this in MATLAB?

Comment: Can you put also your bar-plotting statement in the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, see [this solution](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/58971-bar-plot-with-bars-in-different-colors) on MATLAB Central.

Here's some example code extracted from this. The third column of the data is used to determine which colour to apply to each bar. In your case, you just need to check whether each value is positive or negative and change the colour accordingly.

```
data = [.142 3 1;.156 5 1;.191 2 0;.251 4 0];
%First column is the sorted value
%Second column is the index for the YTickLabel
%Third column is the reaction direction
% Data(1,3) = 1 -> bar in red
% Data(1,3) = 0 -> bar in blue

% For each bar, check direction and change bar colour
H = data(:, 1);
N = numel(H);
for i=1:N
  h = bar(i, H(i));
  if i == 1, hold on, end
  if data(i, 3) == 1
    col = 'r';
  else
    col = 'b';
  end
  set(h, 'FaceColor', col) 
end
```

Comment: Please include relevant extracts from the link

Comment: @Dan, added some code and comments to illustrate the answer. Hopefully, that does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could include your conditions (here `data>0` and `data<0`) as follows:

```
data = rand(8,1) - .5;

figure(1);
clf;
hold on;
bar(data.*(data>0), 'b');
bar(data.*(data<0), 'r');
```

Comment: This won't quite work because you don't have an x axis, so the bars won't be properly ordered. Also you are multiplying the data by the logical vectors instead of using them to call out the data. Having said that, I think the logical indexing solution here is far more elegant than changing each bar color in a loop.

Comment: Nope, and now that I have, I now see how it works. Sorry about that. +1. I do still think you should include an explicit x-axis vector, though. `x=randperm(5*length(data),length(data));` was the vector I used to convince myself that your snippet really does do what it should.